# How to get the last X Opportunities created?

Tags: soql

How do I get the last x opportunities created?  I wrote this query, but isn't it too unselective?

```
SELECT Id, Name, createdDate
From opportunity
order by createdDate Desc
limit 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a dynamic query?

```
public Opportunity[] query's(Integer howMany){

    String qry = 'Select ID, Name, createdDate From Opportunity Order By CreatedDate Desc LIMIT ' + howMany;

     return database.query(qry);

}
```

Since you do not have any filters this would be a selective query as  the created date fields are indexed:

https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: say it wasn't indexed, and I didn't ask SF to index the field. Is there another alternative?

Comment: @nivyaj - The index question is something completely different and has nothing to do with getting x number of records.  The link in my answer and this one will provide you all the info you need: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm